# How to get error log ajax/jquery/mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

How do I find out where did the code went wrong? I don't get any error message.
Ajax call is successfully fired so I suspect the problem is with php.

```
    $.ajax({
        data: id,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'delete.php',
        success: function(){
        }
    });
```

in delete.php (connection with db is fine)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

I think I could figure out if I knew where the problem is...

I tried this, but i get empty field on a, 'success' message on b, and an object on c with status 200...

```
    success: function(a,b,c){
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    },
```

Comment: you are not catching anything in the success callback..

Comment: How do you know there's any error/problem?

Comment: @Fred-ii- nope, didnt work..

Comment: @phillip100 code should delete user from table but it doesnt. Id is correct, and I tried using raw sql query in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what was the problem... but I got it working with

```
    id = $(this).data('id');
    $.post('delete.php', {id: id})
        .done(function(){
            location.reload();
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    data: id,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'delete.php',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data); // log the response
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `echo` some response from your PHP:

**Script**

```
$.ajax({
    data: id,
    type: 'post',
    url: 'delete.php',
    dataType : 'text';
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }  
});
```

**PHP**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', trim($_POST['id']));
if($stmt->execute()){
    echo 'success'; 
}else{
    echo $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I get 'success' message but nothing happens

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli::setAttribute(), i dont use PDO.

Comment: I'll try something else tomorrow, its too late now. Thanks for the help :)